# How to show a livewire component on click?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component that I want to load when clicking a div, and hide it when I click again. How can I do this? I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705040/can-we-load-livewire-component-on-clicking-some-button) but without results. This is where I want to click.

```
<div wire:click="$set('show', true)" id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">                        
          <p>
            Unasigned tickets.
          </p>
      
          {{-- Table --}}
          <livewire:show-gestiones :gestiones="$gestiones" :cortes="$cortes" :estado=5 :show="$show"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need any particular logic in your `show-gestiones` component regarding `$show`, if all you need is to hide it from the browser, you have two options - do it with Alpine (which is client-side only), or do it with Livewire (which will do a network request first).

- Here's approach one; Alpine

Here we use `x-data`, `x-on:click` and `x-show` to toggle the state. Simple JavaScript handlers does this all in the frontned - no need with requests to the server to do this. This also means it will created on first render, and always be there.

```html
<div x-data="{ show: false }"
    x-on:click="show = !show"
    id="collapseOne" 
    class="panel-collapse collapse" 
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="headingOne"
>
    <div class="panel-body" x-show="show">
        <p>
            Unasigned tickets.
        </p>

        {{-- Table --}}
        
        <livewire:show-gestiones :gestiones="$gestiones" :cortes="$cortes" :estado=5 />
    </div>
</div>
```

- Approach 2: Livewire

Here we can use the magic method `$toggle` from Livewire to toggle a boolean on or off. You can then wrap your component in an `@if` condition to that variable. This will also remove the HTML from that Livewire component entirely from the DOM, but it also means that you have to do a roundtrip to the server to do it. This means it will be destroyed when the user hides it, and it will be re-created and re-mounted when its shown.

```html
<div wire:click="$toggle('show')" 
    id="collapseOne" 
    class="panel-collapse collapse" 
    role="tabpanel"
    aria-labelledby="headingOne"
>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>
            Unasigned tickets.
        </p>

        {{-- Table --}}
        @if ($show)
            <livewire:show-gestiones :gestiones="$gestiones" :cortes="$cortes" :estado=5  />
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```